# Authoring a DVD into an image file, from command line

Tags: command-line, video, dvd, ffmpeg, cd-image

I would like to convert a whatever-type video file into an ISO image I could then burn to a DVD (on another computer) - so that the final disc is playable on a regular DVD player.

I already have `ffmpeg` installed with medibuntu, and mpeg output support does seem to work.

Is there a command line tool, or a simple script that I could use to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need specifically mpeg2 output (mpeg1 will do, if you don't mind the loss of resolution, but mpeg4 is outside the spec). You probably want PAL 720x576 25fps 16:9, with MPEG-1 or AC3 audio; or for NTSC 720x480 and 23.97fps (or whatevs). However, you can use the "dvd" target preset to make things easy, simply by running `ffmpeg -i input.avi -target dvd video.mpg`

To turn the mpeg file to an DVD compatible folder structure, you need a tool like dvdauthor. There are probably some frontends to it, but the first example from the book, [chapter 1.2](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/doc/x35.html), is probably sufficient for you. Put that example into file `dvdauthor.xml` and your video to `video.mpg` and execute `dvdauthor -o DVD -x dvdauthor.xml`.

This will result in a directory structure under folder DVD, which you can turn in to an iso file with `genisoimage -dvd-video -o my.iso -v DVD`. You can then copy my.iso to some other system and burn on a disc with `wodim` or some other tool.

The resulting disc should be playable in standalone players, but due to DVD limitations you may run into problems with arbitrary mpeg streams. Some of the problems may be fixed with `dvdauthor` and others with `mplex` from package `mjpegtools`. If you want subtitles, you'll need to learn how to use `spumux`.

Comment: Thanks! That should be enough specs to get me going. I'll research the required ffmpeg options and try this to see if this works.

Answer (score 4):

@taneli's answer covers most of the process but there are a few missing details. Here is my complete process for converting an MP4 file and writing it to a DVD.

I usually only work with MP4 files but I think this should work with most video formats as inputs (as long as it's supported by ffmpeg). I have tested this on NTSC DVD players.

(Tested in Lubuntu 16.04 LTS, Ubuntu Mate 18.04, and Ubuntu Mate 20.04, AMD64)

### 1. Install these packages (using `sudo apt-get install`):

- dvdauthor
- ffmpeg
- wodim
- mkisofs

### 2. Convert your video file to the correct format.

(tested using ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0 and 4.2.2-1ubuntu1)

This depends on the region of the world where you bought the DVD player.

- [NTSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC) Users: `ffmpeg -i yourvideo.mp4 -target ntsc-dvd yourvideo.mpg`
- [PAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL) Users: `ffmpeg -i yourvideo.mp4 -target pal-dvd yourvideo.mpg`
- [SECAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SECAM) Users: May not be supported, see [-target on ffmpeg's documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

### 3. Use dvdauthor to create the dvd filesystem

(Tested using dvdauthor 0.7.0 and 0.7.2)

#### First time setup:

[(source)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dvdauthor/+bug/779501)

Create a file called `video_format` in `~/.config/`.

The file just needs to contain a single line:

- NTSC Users: `NTSC`
- PAL Users: `PAL`
- SECAM Users: `SECAM`? I wasn't able to confirm this.

#### Creating the DVD's Filesystem:

[(source)](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1358462)

```
dvdauthor --title -o yourvideo -f yourvideo.mpg
dvdauthor -o yourvideo -T
```

These commands will write the DVD's filesystem to a folder named "yourvideo".

### 4. Creating an iso

(Tested using mkisofs 1.11.11)

This command will take the contents of the yourvideo folder and convert it into an iso.

`mkisofs -dvd-video -o yourvideo.iso yourvideo/`

### 5. Burn the iso to a blank DVD

(Tested using Wodim 1.1.11)

[(source)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174626/how-do-i-burn-a-dvd-iso-using-the-terminal)

You will likely need to change `/dev/sr0/` to match the device name of your DVD burner.

`sudo wodim -tao speed=2 dev=/dev/sr0 -v -data yourvideo.iso`

Comment: This didn't work. "dvdauthor --title -o yourvideo -f yourvideo.mpg" in Terminal resulted in an endless number of "WARN: unknown mpeg2 aspect ratio 1" lines.

Comment: @HenrikR. what video format were you using? PAL, NTSC or SECAM?

Comment: PAL. This command: "$ ffmpeg -i "Apollo  - Farsight.org.mp4" -target pal-dvd apollo.mpg"

Comment: @HenrikR. Ok, I'll look into it when I get home tonight; I have no PAL devices to test on but I can at least check up to the point where I make the iso.

Comment: Thank you! I look forward to hear from you. Should I try to send you the output of the above ffmpeg command?

Comment: @HenrikR. I can test it on an MP4 I already have on my computer, if I can't reproduce it we'll go from there.

Comment: @HenrikR. Well.... I can't seem to reproduce this with [An Eastern Westerner](https://archive.org/details/KowbojZeWschodu) (note: public domain video), I got no errors or warnings from dvdauthor or ffmpeg. Maybe try a different video, or we might be using different versions of ffmpeg, dvdauthor, etc

Comment: Well... it is THIS video a want to put on DVD. :-) I have put the output from Terminal of ffmpeg and dvdauthor here: https://www.transformation.dk/deling/ffmpeg-error.txt Can you see anything strange?

Comment: In the end http://www.bombono.org/Download did the job! :-) At first I couldn't seem to install it, but now it worked smoothly!