# How do I burn a DVD ISO using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, iso

I have a DVD ISO file and I want to burn through the terminal.

We have many command formats but I am unable to choose the best & safe one. so please give me a best command to burn the ISO through the terminal.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but here are just two ways that I use regularly. Please replace `/dev/sr1` with the device identifier of your target drive (find out what it is with `inxi -d`), and replace `myiso` with your iso and its disk location if necessary.

1. `wodim -eject -tao  speed=2 dev=/dev/sr1 -v -data myiso.iso`
2. `growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr1=myiso.iso`

More information about the read and write capabilities of your drive can be found with the following command, again substituting my example `/dev` with your device identifier:

```
wodim -prcap dev=/dev/sr1
```

For more options relating to `wodim` and `growisofs`, see their respective manpages by entering [`man wodim`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/growisofs) and [`man growisofs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/growisofs).

For installation of `growisofs` :

```
sudo apt install growisofs
```

For installation of `wodim` :

```
sudo apt install wodim
```

Comment: @Mik, can you explain in which package we can find `inxi`?

Comment: @guntbert See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/284635/inxi-installation-on-ubuntu) for how to install `inxi`; I forgot it wasn't in the repositories.

Comment: [wodim should not be used with DVD or BD media](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2018/09/msg01078.html)

Answer (score 28):

Use the following command to locate your DVD drive:

```
wodim --devices
```

It will list an output like below (bold emphasis mine):

```
    wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     0  dev='/dev/sg1' rwrw-- : 'TSSTcorp' 'CDDVDW SH-S223F'
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the above output, we can determine the drive location. In this case, **`/dev/sg1`** is the drive location.

Now, to burn the ISO, you can use the following command:

```
wodim -v dev=/dev/sg1 speed=10 -eject /home/$USER/file.iso
```

Replace `/home/$USER/file.iso` with your preferred path.

Comment: I saw the other answer. I think it's okay to have similar answers on the same thread. I just wanted to post the outputs as well. Also in the accepted answer, it uses inxi which may not ve available on all systems. I have added `wodim --devices` as an alternative.

Comment: `wodim --devices` does not seem to work, use `wodim -checkdrive` instead

Comment: [wodim should not be used with DVD or BD media](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2018/09/msg01078.html)

Comment: Note that this is not working for non-root users as per: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cdrkit/+bug/1769848. Was not working for me, found that issue so I added sudo and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

`bashburn` is your friend.

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bashburn
```

[image]

Currently BashBurn can:

- Burn data CDs/DVDs (Including CDRWs)
- Burn music CDs
- Burn CD/DVD-images
- Rip data/music CDs
- Manipulate ISO-files
- and probably more…

<sub>[Source](http://bashburn.dose.se/)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

An easy to remember command line:

```
wodim CD.iso
```

It will use some defaults and try to guess your drive, which is fine in most cases.

That way you only need to set other options, like speed, if you really need to.

Comment: [wodim should not be used with DVD or BD media](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2018/09/msg01078.html)

Comment: You could use `cdrskin CD.iso`, it also tries to find your device. But with so many similar named tools (cdrtool, cdrkit, cdrskin), it is a little harder to remember, though.

Answer (score 4):

I came to know that we can use dd also to write.Open your terminal ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> )

```
dd if=/path/image.iso of=/dev/cdrom1
```

**if**- Input File, path where you have the image.iso. 
**of**- Output File, where this file have to sent .

If you are trying to burn DVDs using `dd`, then you have to follow below command line.

```bsh
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/dvd=/path/image.iso
```

Comment: I tried this once, made my drive spin like hell.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to replace wodim with Jorg Schilling's `cdrecord` from Brandon Snider's PPA. This has often solved odd burning problems for me and has been tested extensively under my Trusty Tahr installation. First add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brandonsnider/cdrtools
```

Note that this will replace the `wodim` package with `cdrecord` as well as installing `cdda2wav`. Then find the appropriate device address for your DVD drive by running:

```
cdrecord --scanbus
```

Finally run a commandline like the following (your own device address will be different):

```
cdrecord -v dev=0,0,0 -speed 8 driveropts=burnfree fs=32m -eject my_distro.iso
```

A modern `cdrecord` has no issues with either CD or DVD burning, or Bluray for that matter...

**References:**

- [CD and DVD Writing from the Linux Command Line](http://www.andrews-corner.org/burning.html)
- [CDRTools: Brandon Snider](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools)

Answer (score 1):

You could use **Brasero**, using command line arguments

```
brasero --help
```

Comment: No thats failed me many times . thats why I want to try terminal .

Answer (score 1):

```
cdw
```

I would recommend this nice app for burning disks with ncurse interface...

[image: ::: cdw 0.8.0 ::: ScreenShot]