# inxi installation on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, package-management, hardware

I have migrated from Linux Mint to Ubuntu 64(KDE installed). I want check my hardware with **`inxi -F`** command but it returns : **`inxi: command not found`** and as I want to install inxi (**`sudo apt-get install inxi`**) it resturns **`E: Unable to locate package inxi`**

How can I install it in ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inxi` is available without a ppa.

However, you must [enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).

After you enable the universe repository, run the following commands to install inxi:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install inxi
```

Additionally, updates via the `inxi -U` command are disabled by default. If you have problems with the current package managed version, you can update to a more current version of the script by running the following commands:

```
sudo sed -i 's/ATE=false/ATE=true/g' /etc/inxi.conf
sudo inxi -U
```

To view the current version, run the following command:

```
inxi -V | grep inxi
```

[Click here for more information.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126368/167115)

Answer (score 6):

The official repository has changed. Based on the [**new** wiki instructions](https://code.google.com/p/inxi/wiki/Installation), here is how I installed `inxi` on my Xubuntu 12.04 LTS machine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit193/inxi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inxi
```