# Ubuntu Chromium sometimes doesn't load pages

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, xfce, chromium

This is my Chromium version string:

```
 32.0.1700.107 (Developer Build 32.0.1700.107-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20140204.972.1) Ubuntu 13.10
```

I am having issues with pages loading. Immediately after opening the browser, pages do not load. All I get is the title, with a blank page.

The request is going through; that's not the issue. I can inspect the headers, etc.

This leads me to believe it is some sort of rendering issue. After opening a couple of tabs and loading a couple of other pages, the pages start to actually display.

This happens almost every single Chromium startup. It affects the first few tabs open/pages "loaded" (usually by the 5th they render).

[image]
[image]

What could be the issue?

**EDIT**

Alright, we're in business! I ran chromium-browser from the terminal and the first three tabs gave this message:

```
libGL error: open uki failed (Operation not permitted)
libGL error: reverting to (slow) indirect rendering
```

Subsequent tabs (i.e. the ones that actually rendered) did not print any error message.

Now, what does this message mean?

**Edit 2**

Output of `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310] 
           X.Org: 1.14.5 drivers: ati,fglrx (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,radeon) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 6310 Graphics GLX Version: 4.2.12337 - CPC 13.101
```

I feel like it may be an issue with the ATI fglrx drivers.

Comment: Do you get any error messages if you start chromium from a terminal? They might be informative.

Comment: @terdon see updated answer above

Comment: Hmm, graphics card and driver info please. If you don't have it already, [install inxi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/284635/inxi-installation-on-ubuntu) and run `inxi -G`.

Comment: @terdon See updated answer above for output of `inxi -G`.

Comment: OK, you're using the proprietary drivers, see if there's a newer version of the driver [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) (kai to'svhsa gia na mhn mas kraxoun :).

Comment: @terdon OK, I can update n.10 to n.12, which I am doing now.

Comment: @terdon Well, using the open-source drivers mitigates the issue. I will try reinstalling the proprietary drivers again, but if it does not fix the problem I can simply stick with the open-source ones.

Comment: Cool, please consider writing an answer explaining what you did and accepting it. It will get you some rep and help future visitors.

Comment: Alright, I'm using the proprietary driver again. It still gives me the LibGL error, but it actually renders the content. Will do for the answer

Comment: You might also be able to use the `--disable-gpu` flag with the proprietary drivers, but some things may be slower.

Comment: @saiaroct895 Interesting. But how is it explained that *every single time* it was *exactly* for the first three requests that the error came up, then everything worked fine? I ended up just using the open-source drivers.

Comment: Almost a week later, still not resolved.