# Primary display unknown

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution, display

I'm new to Ubuntu, I recently installed 12.04.4 LTS.

My display is not recognized by Ubuntu.

Display: Kent Modular Electronics (KME) 29LR1901A51UN/1 connected via RGBHV BNC connectors.

Video card: Nvidia GeForce 7600 GT

Under windows I'm using 1280x1024.

I tried different drivers using 'Additional drivers (jockey-kde / jockey-gtk), right now using nvidia_304.116 via jockey-gtk: 'This driver is activated but not currently in use.'
Trying different drivers doesn't yield different resolutions, and in Displays my screen doesn't get recognized. Display Unknown.

Via https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution I tried 'Adding undetected resolutions'.

```
$ cvt 1280 1024

# 1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

after which

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

This will add the mode to the list, but as TV-0 disconnected. I'm not able to use the mode.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   576x432        60.1  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2     60.3     56.3  
   320x240        60.1  
TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x26c)  109.0MHz
    h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock   63.7KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock   59.9Hz
```

From here I don't know what I'm supposed to do. Having done this doens't change anything yet. After rebooting this TV-0 mode is lost.

Trying to add the mode:

```
$ xrandr --addmode TV-0 1280x1024_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  25
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

Is this wrong?

---

Installed inxi:

```
inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA NV44 [GeForce 6200 LE] 
           X.Org: 1.14.5 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau) Resolution:     1024x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: GeForce 6200 LE/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 2.1.2 NVIDIA 304.116
```

Comment: What mode? What do you actually see? Who gives the "'This driver is activated but not currently in use." message? What's TV-0? Please [edit] your question and clarify. Also add the output of running `xrandr` in the terminal.

Comment: Edited.
I don't know what TV-0 is. This is what my mode is added to after running cvt 1280 1024 60.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How many displays do you have? It looks like you have just one connected and that is using a VGA cable. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm using one display connected via RGBHV - BNC connectors to VGA, yes.

Comment: Please give us more information. How exactly did you add this resolution? What was the exact command you used? Have you restarted since installing the nvidia driver? What do you actually see right now? The display _is_ recognized, is the problem that it has the wrong resolution?

Comment: Thanks so far. I'm new to this so I don't know which information is relevant. 
I first tried just finding drivers via 'Additional drivers'. This didn't help finding the right resolution (1280x1024). I tried multiple options given, but none allowed for more resolutions. 
Then I found the possibility to add modes using $ cvt 1280 1024 60
The result was the added mode in TV-0, but it says it is disconnected.

Comment: So what I see is that the mode 1280x1024_60.00 is added to TV-0 disconnected. From here I don't know what I'm supposed to do. 
$ xrandr --addmode yields: X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
In displays I don't see any new resolutions and after rebooting the information is lost.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include this information. Show us the exact command you used to add the mode. Also answer my other question, what exactly do you see? Is the display ignored or is the resolution simply wrong?

Comment: Edited. Anything else missing?

Comment: The only thing missing is whether or not your screen is actually being used. You say it's not recognized, do you mean that nothing appears on your screen or does it work but with the wrong resolution? Also, what happens when you run `xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024_60.00` ? Does that make the mode available in the Displays drop down?

Comment: The screen works just fine, but with a low/wrong resolution (1024x768).
--addmode VGA-0 yield the same error as shown with TV-0 
No new mode is added to the drop down menu.

Comment: Ok, first of all the Nvidia proprietary drivers maybe don't have support for NV4B family, that is GeForce 7600 GT. For that use nouveau's, so installing nvidia drivers is probably doing more harm than good. Have you tried without the nvidia drivers?

Comment: Tried what exactly? Adding the mode without having activated the drivers? I can remove the drivers [like this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) and then try adding the mode?

Comment: @Braiam You were right. The additional drivers were causing the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed all additional drivers like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely).

Added the mode like [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions):

```
$ cvt 1280 1024 60

$ xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync 

$ xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1280x1024_60.00
```

Display jumped to correct resolution after adding the mode to VGA-1.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   1280x1024_60.00   59.9* 
TV-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Thank you Braiam and terdon.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make sure you can add the desired resolution. Based on the output of your `cvt` command, you need to run these two:

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024_60.00
```

That should make the new mode available in the Displays dropdown menu. If that works, see here for how to make it permanent:

[Why don't my lightdm.conf edits affect my desktop screen resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/q/445957/85695)

---

If that doesn't work, my guess is that the driver you are using can't support the resolution. In this case, we will have to make sure you are using the nvidia driver and to do that, you will need to [install `inxi`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284635/inxi-installation-on-ubuntu), then edit your question and add the output of `inxi -G`. Once we have seen the output of that we'll be able to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Adding the mode doesn't work. I installed inxi, edited the question.

Comment: @Oliver OK, I was not sure if you had run both commands using  `VGA-0` instead of `TV-0`. Based on your `inxi` output, you are indeed using the nvidia driver. Do you have an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file? If you don't I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I do have that file. It contains:

Section "Device"
 Identifier "Default Device"
 Option "NoLogo" "True"
EndSection

Comment: @Oliver hmm, none of that should affect anything. Braiam might be on to something though, I guess it's possible that your 10 year old card is not supported by the latest drivers. It might well be a good idea to try the open source drivers as he suggested instead.

Comment: [Apparently got this one right ;)](http://askubuntu.com/a/456286/169736)