# How to fix inxi: "Error: weather info downloaded but no data detected."?

Tags: command-line, weather, inxi

When I use the following command:

```
inxi -w
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: weather info downloaded but no data detected.
```

I have tried using the `-W Location` option but I still get the same error.

I have also tried using a different location and I have tried using the location zip code and also the location City,State format and I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Could you try a more recent version via [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~unit193/+archive/ubuntu/inxi?field.series_filter=bionic)? *inxi*'s dev [suggests](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/inxi-w-fails-to-report-weather-conditions-4175649814/#post5971860) using a newer version may help.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks! I cloned pinxi from github and installed it to a local directory and it works now. I also tried the main version inxi 3.0.32-00 (2019-02-07) which is used by the ppa and that one also works. If you make your comment an answer I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developer of *inxi* [has indicated](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/inxi-w-fails-to-report-weather-conditions-4175649814/#post5971860) that the source for weather data used by the version of *inxi* in the Bionic Beaver repositories is no longer available.

> The data source in legacy inxi (legacy in this case is inxi version 3.0.31 or older) is gone, that is why 3.0.32 was hurried out the door. There is nothing you can do to get -w data in inxi except upgrade to current inxi.
>
> Note that new inxi also has the --weather-source option, takes values 1-6, but 1 is the one that went offline this month.
>
> All of them are quite different, internally I pick a default source to use based on which seems most consistent, or you can force it.

Regularly updated versions of inxi are available via Unit 193's [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~unit193/+archive/ubuntu/inxi?field.series_filter=bionic) or from the developer's [GitHub page](https://github.com/smxi/inxi).

Comment: The options recently changed, only 1-5 are supported now that the old 1 option is completely gone (the previous sources were all moved down one spot in the list since there was no point in having a dead source). But a complete answer that covers the matter well, thanks. I'm sure this will be referenced many times in searches, so I'm glad you posted the full explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can update the inxi package by editing /etc/inxi.conf

You can either comment out `B_ALLOW_UPDATE=false` or change it to `B_ALLOW_UPDATE=true`

Save the file then in terminal do `sudo inxi -U`

The updated inxi will use weatherbit.io

Comment: Technically, the default source is set based on what seems to offer the most accurate results for most users, so if a better source is found, that would become default, and weatherbit would then be switched to alternate status. The same applies to the --weather-source values of 1-5 (currently), those can change and refer to different sources, just as the default might change if it seems like a good idea. inxi will print out the source however in these cases so users can see what is being used for default or alternates.

Comment: I feel that it must be said that this answer is the best and most simple solution to the problem. However, I accepted the answer by DK Bose because their answer first pointed out that the old version was the problem. Thanks! (upvote)

Comment: I used `sed` to edit the file: `sudo sed -i 's/ATE=false/ATE=true/g' /etc/inxi.conf`