# How to burn an Ubuntu ISO image on a DVD on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center, iso, burning

I have a Ubuntu image file (.iso) and I'd like to burn the image file into a DVD, is there any software for this purpose on Ubuntu?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/174626/how-do-i-burn-a-dvd-iso-using-the-terminal

Answer (score 35):

1. Insert a blank DVD into your burner. A *CD/DVD Creator*, *Choose Disc Type* or *Blank Disc* window might pop up. Close this, because you will not be using it.

   [image]
   <sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>
2. 16.04 and later no longer comes with a CD/DVD burner, so install Brasero Disc Burner. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
    sudo apt install brasero
   ```
3. Open Brasero and click on the *Burn image* button.

   [image]
4. Select the ISO you downloaded in the *Select a disc image to write* box and your DVD drive in the *Select a disc to write to* box and click the *Burn* button.

   [image]
   <sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>
5. Once the DVD is burned, you can restart your computer and try or install Ubuntu.

   [image]
   <sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Let me see if I got it right, you have an Ubuntu image file and you want to burn it into a DVD. Right?

If so, just open your Dash menu click on Applications (the icon with an "A" in the bottom) and in "Filter" look for "Media" an application called Brasero Disk Burner will show up, just click it and burn you image.

Doubts? Follow this tutorial (click in the image for a fullsize version).

[image: Tutorial]

Comment: Hi ZigndBy,
  Thanks for the answer. By using the above procedure can we make bootable DVD of Ubuntu?

Comment: @udaykumar yes you can! A Ubuntu bootable DVD is nothing but a simple iso burned into a DVD/CD. The option you need to choose on Brasero is the last on the list at the left side called "Burn image".

Comment: Note that on Xenial/16.04 Brasero is no longer installed by default, so you won't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You could install `k3b`, too :

```bsh
sudo apt install k3b
```

When you create a bootable CD/DVD in `k3b`, simply drag-and-drop the iso-image from the above file-window into the below window of the to-burn-CD/DVD.

---

Or you can use the command `wodim` in a terminal to burn a bootable CD/DVD.

Install if necessary :

```bsh
sudo apt install wodim
```

Then :

```bsh
cd ~/Downloads
wodim -v -eject name-of-file.iso
```

Comment: Variables are case-sensitive on *nix, so replace `$user` with `$USER`.

Comment: this is shortest solution of this thread. Below solutions are only clicki-bunti for windows-addicted users.