# What program and what write speed?

Tags: dvd

What program is best to use for burning ubuntu 12.04.3 lts desktop and what write speed is the best to burn it
i use the program imageburn is good?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to burn an ISO-image into a DVD on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307742/how-to-burn-an-iso-image-into-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)

Comment: the first part(burning) is duplicate.the second part(speed) depends upon your choice.choose lower speed if you have enough time.

Comment: Were you able to successfully burn the disc?

Answer (score 0):

The speed at which you burn the disc should depend on the quality of your burner (hardware) and the disc itself. If your hardware and discs are relatively new, feel free to use the highest speed that *both* are rated for. For example, if your hardware is capable of burning at 52x for CD-Rs and 32x for CD-RWs, and you have a CD-R rated for 40x, take the lowest of the 2 (52x and 40x) and burn at that speed (40x). If you have reason to be concerned about the quality of the CD, you can always burn at a lower speed to be safer. And if you run into any problems while using the burned CD, you can try burning it again at a lower speed. To my knowledge, there can be no disadvantage to burning a disc at a lower speed (except that it will take more time); nonetheless, with modern hardware, media, and software, there is practically no reason to ever burn CDs at very low speeds like 1x, 2x, and 4x.

Regarding the software, if you meant [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/), that should work just fine. It's a popular image burner with good reviews.