# What files should be on an Ubuntu installation DVD?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, livedvd

I have two DVDs. I cannot install from either. One is xxx.iso the other contains files: .disk, boot, casper … etc

What should I see if I display the files that are on a proper DVD?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't burn the downloaded *.iso file properly to create a bootable DVD. **How did you create the DVDs?** It won't work if you simply drag the *.iso file to an empty DVD nor if you drag the files contained in the *.iso file to an empty DVD.

Comment: The one with the .iso file on it is improperly made. The one with "boot", "casper", etc sounds correct, so what happens when you try to boot from it? What instructions did you follow? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from the DVD that contains the Ubuntu 18.04 .iso image (ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso) burned on it with a CD/DVD burner. For more information about how to burn an Ubuntu installation DVD on Ubuntu read [How to burn an Ubuntu ISO image on a DVD on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307742/how-to-burn-an-ubuntu-iso-image-on-a-dvd-on-ubuntu/828879#828879).

[image]
<sup>**contents of the Ubuntu 18.04 .iso image in Archive Manager**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Ubuntu 10.04 CD from Canonical**</sup>

Comment: I've tried booting from both. Won't boot from either. BIOS is set to boot from DVD. Can boot from other, unrelated DVDs

Comment: Does your target Ubuntu installation computer have a USB port, and do you have a 4GB or larger USB flash drive? If so, read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/674454#674454).