# Problem installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

i have been using ubuntu for a wile now and i have recently got a new PC. The PC is a dell optiplex gx520. i try to put un the ubuntu DVD i got from a magazine called Linux Format. The CD worked on my other computers, but this one will not load it. I then tryed it on one of my other computers to see if it would work but no.

The second computer kept on crashing when it got to the graphical screen.

Thanks, Cassius

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to burn an Ubuntu ISO image on a DVD on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307742/how-to-burn-an-ubuntu-iso-image-on-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) and [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like its the DVD's fault.

Follow these instructions from the official page:
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0
-how to create a bootable USB-Stick

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0
-how to install Ubuntu