# CD / DVD burner softweare

Tags: 20.04, cd, burner

I recently upgraded to 20.04.  i don't see a CD / DVD burner icon, and can't seem to find a burner package on the ubuntu software site.  Can someone tell me how to find the burner software, if it is installed with the package, or the name of a package ( and what category it is under ) on the software library.

Thanks.

Comment: Brasero is what your looking for should be in the software center

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to burn an Ubuntu ISO image on a DVD on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307742/how-to-burn-an-ubuntu-iso-image-on-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Brasero should have came with your distribution. You can also try to install one from the Software Store. If you are more of a power user you can:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
sudo synaptic
```

Then search for a number of the burner software options.

I personally use **k3b** for my DVD recordings.

Answer (score 0):

You need Brasero, It is specifically good at performing this single task. To add the package to your system just:

1. click [this link](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Brasero) to be redirected to the package page on the GNOME wiki. You know GNOME is the desktop environment installed on Ubuntu by default.
2. scroll down until you find "Getting Brasero" and click it, here is a picture [just click the big button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pnzh.png)
3. scroll down to the packages area and [click the link corresponding to Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa2wa.png) since we are in askubuntu. It is an apt link
4. choose your software manager to open the link [here is picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAiyN.png)
   I think this is just equivalent to running "sudo apt install brasero" on terminal.

Now to burn the iso file you into a CD or DVD just do:

1. Insert a blank CD into your burner. [A ‘CD/DVD Creator’, ‘Choose Disc Type’ or ‘Blank Disc’ window might pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyhuN.jpg). Close this, because we will not be using it.
2. Start Brasero, just type brasero on the menu and click on it.
3. Click on the ‘Burn image’ button
4. Select the ISO you wish to burn in the ‘Select a disc image to write’ box and your DVD drive in the ‘Select a disc to write to’ box ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K10Hf.jpg)) and click the ‘Burn’ button.
5. You get a pop-up window that says "Image successfully burnt to DVD" if the task is completed successfully.

Credits to the ["How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu 16.04"](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu#1-getting-started) tutorial